# programs for creating diagrams

Tags: graphics, diagrams, graphs, technical-drawing

Does anybody know of some programs I can use to make diagrams that look like the following

[image]

I would use the above diagram directly, however due to copyright issues, this is not an option for me.  What is the most painless way I can do this and make similar diagrams as well?  If standard MS Office tools can, please share that information as well.

Comment: Take a look at [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) and [`pgfplotstable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina hmm, this looks like an interesting tool, but unforunately, I do not have data points to feed the program.  If there is a way to just trace/draw the curves, that would be ideal

Comment: You can draw the axis with Pgfplots and draw on the axis via TikZ.

Comment: @suzu, get the datapoints from the diagram, will take only little effort if compared to tracing it. Alternatively you could also draw it in Inkscape and export it as TikZ code.

Comment: You can extract the data points from the diagram using, for example, [XYscan](http://star.physics.yale.edu/~ullrich/xyscanDistributionPage/) (open source, Linux/Windows/Mac).

Comment: Another possibility for getting the data from the diagram: [g3data/g3data2](http://www.frantz.fi/software/g3data.php) (just for the sake of completeness).

Comment: The diagram is a mixture between data points being plotted automatically and manual annotations. An excellent tool for visualizing data is R (http://www.r-project.org/, in combination with ggplot2). It can emit many formats of which EPS and PDF would be ideal for latex and pdflatex. It might be overkill if you are mostly plotting real-valued data points like shown here. As R is batch oriented (like LaTeX), manual annotations are more difficult to apply than with an interactive program.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest PgfPlots for the best results in terms of quality and harmony with the rest of your documents. Another nice tool is Python's MatPlotLib (which supports Bezier curves drawing), which supports LaTeX style in titles, formulas, axis labels ecc...You could also use Inkscape, which can produce directly Tikzpicture environments if you use the code you find here 
http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/

Comment: matplotlib 1.2 (released a few weeks ago) can actually [export pgf](http://matplotlib.org/users/pgf.html?highlight=pgf).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty close to what you want. Some things are left to be filled. It is made with [jpgfdraw](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/apps/jpgfdraw/). The source file its [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxaG1GVbo3S5SkpuMjA5V21pZEU) [image]

Answer (score 0):

I would import the drawing into Inkscape, an trace it. This shoul lead to an acceptable result. Although, reading the data from the chart and replotting using Excel could be less work, as was already suggested in the comments.